# How to use lapply to skimr:: skim multiple data frames then export them to Excel?

Tags: r, lapply, data-wrangling

I have 2 data frames(more in real life). My goal is to apply the skim function then export them as excel to a folder. They would also have different Excel file names.

`df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(3, 5), y = seq(1, 5, 1), ID = letters[1:5])`

`df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(5, 5), y = seq(2, 6, 1), ID = letters[6:10])`

I need the short way to accomplish the below:

for df1:

`df1_summary<-skim(df1)`

`df1_summary<-as.data.frame(df1_summary)`

`write_xlsx(df1_summary,"df1_summary.xlsx")`

for df2:

`df2_summary<-skim(df2)`

`df2_summary<as.data.frame(df2_summary)`

`write_xlsx(df2_summary,"df2_summary.xlsx")`

So far I know,
`df.list<-list(df1, df2)`

`lapply(df.list, function(x) ...`

I have many more than 2 data frames for this task in real life. Any help to shorten the process would helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the function after placing the datasets in a `list`

```
library(skimr)
lst1 <- lapply(list(df1, df2), function(x) {

    dat <-  as.data.frame(skim(x)) 
    })

names(lst1) <- c('df1_summary', 'df2_summary')
Map(function(x, y) write_xlsx(x, paste0(y, ".xlsx")), lst1, names(lst1))
```

Comment: Thank! is the "Map" there all lowercase?

Comment: @merry123 base R is `M` caps, but there is a `map` from `purrr`